# find and output duplicated files in python , The line is seperated by comma

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, file, spyder

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
Name1, 123
Name2, 123
Name1, 456
Name3, 345
Name2, 456
Name1, 123
Name3, 123
Name4, 789
Name2, 789
Name5, 136
```

here is my code:

```
import pyspark
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv

with open('filehash.csv') as filehash:
    csv_reader=csv.reader(filehash, delimiter=",")

for filehash in csv_reader:

    print (filehash)
    csv_reader.duplicated()
```

I know, between csv_reader. and .duplicated I need an attribute. But my .csv table has no attributes. I guess because of the comma
So, how can I get my int-values after my comma??

The expected output should be:

```
True, True True, False, True, True, True, True, True, False
```

Comment: Please post a sample of the CSV file an the expected output.

Comment: ['Name1', '123']
['Name2', '123']
['Name1', '456']
['Name3', '345']
['Name2', '456']
['Name1', '123']
['Name3', '123']
['Name4', '789']
['Name2', '789']
['Name5', '136']

Comment: Edit the question with the data and the expected out, it's easier to read.

Comment: And my expected output should be like: true, true, true, false...

Comment: Thank you for editing. I'm new in stackoverflow.. I'll edit it next time better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the `csv` file using pandas use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) to get which values from the second column are duplicates:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None)
duplicates = df[df.columns[1]].duplicated(keep=False).to_list()

duplicates
# [True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, False]
```